# Excluding specific string within dir command

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, dir

```
setlocal
set "s=DIR C:\Folder /S /Q^|FIND /i "Owner" ^|findstr /m /i "\.mkv$""
for /f "Tokens=5,6*" %%a in ('%s%') do >>%tmp%\list.txt echo %%a %%b %%c
```

This code lists mkv files owned by OWNER in lists.txt 
But I want to exclude some strings. For example if mkv's name has "sample" in it I don't want to list it.

I couldn't get through this. I come to a deadend. Is it possible to do that? If it is how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another `find`to your `%S%`:

```
|find /v /i "sample"
```